# get process id through Perl script

Tags: shell, grep, ps

In my script, I am executing `cat`, then trying to `grep` to get the process id.

I used this :

```
ps | grep -e \'cat$\' | cut -d\' \' -f2 | head -n 1
```

but it's not returning anything.

Comment: How are you executing `cat`? There is probably a more direct way to get the PID than by listing processes.

Comment: Are the two commands running in sequence? If you're executing cat, waiting for it to finish and then using ps, then there won't be a PID to find.

Comment: Try : ps | grep -e 'cat$' | cut -d ' ' -f2 | head -n 1 . Hint: check your chain of pipes step by step to see if the results are as you expect.

Comment: To get the PID in a Perl script you can use the `$$` special variable.

Comment: So you are not using `perl`?

Comment: @Joni and chooban: i will running cat in background, like 'cat &' then grep it

Comment: [spam] If you want to just `kill` the `cat`, try using the command `curiosity`, that is supposed to kill cats ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a background process in a shell with `program &` you can access the PID of the child process through `$!`.

For example:

```
bash-4.2.37$ cat &
[1] 9664
bash-4.2.37$ CAT_PID=$!
...time passes...
bash-4.2.37$ echo $CAT_PID
9664
```

Comment: This would fail, if the user runs another b/g process in between?

Comment: The trick is to store the pid somewhere so you can use it later.